# HTML Detect what image extension in <img> tag

Tags: php, html, image

I'm still new to PHP and HTML in general. I'm trying to do a script which I can upload image and then shows the image on a panel. It works as intended but now I'm having a problem if the uploaded image is of different extensions.

For example, the usual image that I upload to show it on the panel is JPEG. But when I upload a PNG image, the image won't load because the  tag is already hardcoded to show every uploaded images as .jpg. The panel which shows the image looks like this:

```
$html  = '<div style="width: 100%"><a href="'.$this->database('source').'" target="_blank"><img alt="'.$this->database('char_name').'-'.$this->database('char_origin').'" src="'.HTML_PATH_PLUGINS_DB.'files/image.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a></div>';
```

What I want to do is to have something like a code to detect the extension of the image or perhaps just a usage of wildcards so that the browser will load the image regardless of its extension.

I tried replacing the .jpg with .*, but of course, it doesn't work since it is enclosed in "". I wish there's an easy method to do this. I tried looking all over Stackoverflow but I still don't understand how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Here's the whole code:

```
class PLUGIN_PORTRAIT_PANEL extends Plugin
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->fields = array(
        'char_name'=>'',
        'char_name_url'=>'',
        'char_origin'=>'',
        'char_origin_url'=>'',
        'source'=>'',
        'image'=>''
        );
    }

    public function dashboard_config()
    {
        global $Language;

        // Character Name
        $html  = Html::label(array('content'=>$Language->get('CHAR_NAME')));
        $html .= Html::input(array('name'=>'char_name', 'type'=>'text', 'value'=>$this->database('char_name')));

        $html .= Html::label(array('content'=>$Language->get('CHAR_NAME_URL')));
        $html .= Html::input(array('name'=>'char_name_url', 'type'=>'text', 'value'=>$this->database('char_name_url')));

        // Character Origin
        $html .= Html::label(array('content'=>$Language->get('CHAR_ORIGIN')));
        $html .= Html::input(array('name'=>'char_origin', 'type'=>'text', 'value'=>$this->database('char_origin')));

        $html .= Html::label(array('content'=>$Language->get('CHAR_ORIGIN_URL')));
        $html .= Html::input(array('name'=>'char_origin_url', 'type'=>'text', 'value'=>$this->database('char_origin_url')));

        // Image Source
        $html .= Html::label(array('content'=>$Language->get('SOURCE')));
        $html .= Html::input(array('name'=>'source', 'type'=>'text', 'value'=>$this->database('source')));

        // Image
        $html .= Html::label(array('content'=>$Language->get('UPLOAD')));
        $html .= Html::input(array('name'=>'image', 'type'=>'file'));
        $html .= Html::div(array('class'=>'tip', 'content'=>$Language->get('UPLOAD_NOTICE')));

        return $html;
    }

    public function blog_body()
    {
        $html  = '<div style="width: 100%"><a href="'.$this->database('source').'" target="_blank"><img alt="'.$this->database('char_origin').'-'.$this->database('char_name').'" src="'.HTML_PATH_PLUGINS_DB.'ddok/'.$this->database('image').'" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /></a></div>';
        $html .= '<a href="'.$this->database('char_name_url').'" target="_blank">'.$this->database('char_name').'</a> from <a href="'.$this->database('char_origin_url').'" target="_blank">'.$this->database('char_origin').'</a>.';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are doing hardcode? It is just simple task. Simply fetch desired image from database

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do right now. How do I add the uploaded image into the database? I've uploaded the whole of the current code if it helps.

Comment: what you can do is just add the url to database and store image on disk and then just use the url from database to display the image

Comment: @HarshalBulsara: How do actually do it so that the image uploaded will automatically add it's name and extension to the database? I tried doing it but all I get in return is an empty string once the image was uploaded. I don't know how to get the name and extension of the file to store it into the database automatically through the code.

Comment: The file resides in the `/tmp` folder when you upload it. All the information you need is stored in the multi-dimensional `$_FILES` array. You can use `move_uploaded_file` to move the images from the `/tmp` folder and then store that path in the database. Don't forget to check if there's not already some in the target location tho (incl. if the folder-tree already exists). You wouldn't want to accidentally overwrite other images.

Comment: @Allendar: The script (or plugin) is working inside a function of a system I'm using as its base. The uploaded image is automatically moved to a folder. AFAIK, the image is also uploaded using the system's own uploader script. If I set the <input name= as 'image', the name of the uploaded image will be image. I wonder if there's actually a way I can preserve the name of the file. Do I just remove the 'name' inside of the <input> tag?

Comment: $_FILES are not inside your $_POST, they are separated. If you do a `var_dump` on the `$_FILES` array you can easily see the `name` key-value inside each `$_FILES[0]['name']` (indexed upload). Giving the file field a name probably won't matter much for the PHP backend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to pick up the original file name extension, by using

```
$_FILES['theFormField']['name']
```

and generate your suffix from that. Flawed, but still:

```
//on post
//get suffix.
$a = explode('.',$_FILES['theField']['name']);
$theSuffixToBeSavedInDatabase = $a[1];

//later, upon view
//get the suffix stored in db.
$suffix = $rec['FileSuffix']
echo '<img src='" . $rec['RadomFileNameWithoutSuffix'] . '.' . $suffix . '" />';
```

Or if you allready have a bunch of images with unknown type stored in the database, grab the first three bytes and look what it says and generate your suffix from that.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find the extension of the file, or in this case, the image.

To do this, you can use the [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) as provided in PHP.

So, it would be used like this, as shown below in the example.

```
$file = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/black.png');
echo $file['extension'], "\n";
```

Here's the [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/S1s7ly) for an example.

This returns the file extension `.png`.

Now, you'd also need the file name, so this is done as shown below:

```
echo $file['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

This would return `black`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do I get the extension to show inside my <img> tag?

Comment: You can use my answer as a building block.

Comment: I tried to, but, from what I read in the pathinfo manual page, it will not return the extension of the file unless specified. This is the problem, because the type of the image uploaded will is random. How do I actually use it to give me the extension of the file without having to specify it myself?